# Create view display block for Organic Groups with specific criteria

Tags: views, organic-groups

I have created a OG view display block that shows the subgroups of a parent group. The issue I'm having is that when there is a private group that's a subgroup of the parent group being shown, it shows the message "-Private Group-". I would instead like the group to not appear in the list at all if the user is not subscribed to it, but show as a link to that subgroup if the user viewing is subscribed to the private group.

I have attached a screenshot of the current view configuration.

[image: View display block]

Comment: If the user *is* a member of the private group currently, what do you see?  The group name, linked to the group?  Or does it still just show "-Private Group-"?

Comment: Yeah I see the group name linked to the group.